# OS Graphics problems when I start Steam on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, steam, amd-graphics

When I start Steam the OS graphics get messed up.
I have attached a screenshot to prove it, but the transaparency that you can see it's only in the screenshot, when the graphics get messed up, I see black instead.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4 and my specs are:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
GPU: Radeon 5700XT
RAM: 16Gb DDR4

I've tried installing through command line and downloading Steam from the official site, always deleting and purging steam installer and steam data.

[ubuntu graphics messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOLZO.jpg)

Comment: Make sure Ubuntu is fully updated.

Comment: I'm sure that Ubuntu is fully updated